# Issue with rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run rake test and got this message, the system cannot find the path specified. i am new to rails. please help. thank you

[snipet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGhgu.jpg)

Comment: Can you run `rake -v test` and post the output?

Comment: still the same message shows up  "the system cannot find the path specified "

Comment: What about `bundle exec rake test` ?

Comment: The same message shows up. "the system cannot find the path specified "

Comment: Can you ran any of the following at all? `gem -v`, `rails -v` if not you should add the executables path to the PATH system variable

Comment: gem -v and rails -v (5.0.1)runs well. but when i run rake -v test or bundle exec rake test. the same message shows up . I've added to path still won't work

Comment: Does rake appear in the list when you run `gem list rake`?

Comment: every thing works fine now. I reinstalled rails and added this to Rails application configuration:

    config.web_console.development_only = false